# Trying to iterate over array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

So I am trying to tell whether the sheep is present or not (true), and if it is (false) to pop it out of the array.

I am new to CodeWars, and to be honest.. I haven't been really working with for loops that much lately.

Question: 
Consider an array/list of sheep where some sheep may be missing from their place. We need a function that counts the number of sheep present in the array (true means present).

My code :

```
function countSheeps(arrayOfSheep) {
  for (i = 0; i < arrayOfSheep.length; i++ ) {
    console.log(arrayOfSheep[i])

    sheep = 0
    if (arrayOfSheep === true) {
      return sheep++
    } else {
      arrayOfSheep.pop()
    }
  }
  console.log(sheep)
}
```

The test:

```
var array1 = [true,  true,  true,  false,
              true,  true,  true,  true ,
              true,  false, true,  false,
              true,  false, false, true ,
              true,  true,  true,  true ,
              false, false, true,  true ];

Test.expect(countSheeps(array1) == 17, "There are 17 sheeps in total")
```

Comment: You didn't even mention the question. `:(` Are you trying to count the number of `true`?

Comment: Not getting what is your question here?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman sorry yes, let me edit it to make the question more apparent. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the number of true members in an array of boolean values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317140/count-the-number-of-true-members-in-an-array-of-boolean-values)

Comment: `sheep = 0` must be outside forloop

Comment: @kmoser yes I that is helpful I am trying to refactor my code lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a lot of work required to fix this, let's see the problems:

```js
function countSheeps(arrayOfSheep) {
  for (i = 0; i < arrayOfSheep.length; i++ ) {
    console.log(arrayOfSheep[i])

    sheep = 0
    if (arrayOfSheep === true) {
      return sheep++
    } else {
      arrayOfSheep.pop()
    }
  }
  console.log(sheep)
}
```

```js
    if (arrayOfSheep === true) {
```

`arrayOfSheep` is an array.  It looks like you're looping through the array and would want to use `i` as an index, so that would be `arrayOfSheep[i]`.

```
      return sheep++
```

This would take the value of `sheep` increment `sheep` to 1 and return the original value 0 immediately, skipping the rest of the array.  Your function would return 0 the first time it found a true value.

```js
arrayOfSheep.pop()
```

This removes the last element from the array.  Something you certainly don't want to do before you check it...

```
sheep = 0
```

It seems like you want sheep to store the count of 'true' values in the array.  Resetting it to 0 every time through your array would mean you would only count the final 'true' value.

```js
  console.log(sheep)
}
```

There's no return statement here.  If you make it to the end of the array, your function will return `undefined` by default.  Running tests on codewars I'm guessing you're seeing either `0` or `undefined` as your result.

Keeping close to your code and making it work would be something like this:

```
function countSheeps(arrayOfSheep) {
  let sheep = 0; // set value once before counting
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfSheep.length; i++ ) {
    if (arrayOfSheep === true) {
      sheep++; // increment value of sheep variable
    }
  }
  return sheep; // return the cound in the sheep variable as your function return value
}
```

There are faster methods in newer javascript though.  You could [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the
sheep for true values and return the length of the result:

```js
function countSheep(arrayOfSheep) {
  // trueValues will only havet he true values from arrayOfSheep
  let trueValues = arrayOfSheep.filter(sheep => sheep === true);
  return trueValues.length;
}
```

Another way seems perfect for [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) which operates on each element of the array:

```js
function countSheep(arrayOfSheep) {
  return arrayOfSheep.reduce((acc, sheep) => sheep ? acc + 1 : acc, 0);
}
```

This starts with the 0 value and calls the function for each element in the array.  If the value is true, it returns `acc + 1`, otherwise it returns `acc` without changes.  So the first time through the loop `acc` will be 0 and `sheep` will be the first value in the array.  If that is true, it will return 1, otherwise it will return 0.  The next time through the array acc will be that return value (0 or 1) and sheep will be the next element in the array.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time out to try and get my code working, I can't seem to console log sheep this way.  I think I had code similar to this at one point but as I kept just trying things.

Comment: You're welcome.  I think the `return` inside your loop was skipping most of the array and your `console.log(sheep)` was never getting hit since it's outside the loop and you would return before ever hitting that point.

Comment: I really like the filter method, I guess I am just trying to over complicate simple things because I am stressing about getting better with loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` method on Array.

```js
var array1 = [true,  true,  true,  false,
              true,  true,  true,  true ,
              true,  false, true,  false,
              true,  false, false, true ,
              true,  true,  true,  true ,
              false, false, true,  true ];
              
              
getCount = (data) => data.filter(d => d)

console.log(getCount(array1).length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below will get the job done.

```
function countSheep(input){
    let sheep = 0;
    for(i in input){
        if(input[i]){
            sheep++;
        }
    }
    return sheep;
}
```

Comment: `.filter()` would be better, but your answer for question is relatable

Answer (score 0):

I am probably misinterpreting your question, but if you are trying to count the number of positive Booleans, please take a look at the following example.

```js
const array1 = [true,  true,  true,  false,
              true,  true,  true,  true ,
              true,  false, true,  false,
              true,  false, false, true ,
              true,  true,  true,  true ,
              false, false, true,  true ]
              
console.log(array1.filter(entry => entry).length)
```